# Using p5.js to change the processing codes and display the shape

Tags: processing, p5.js

I want to change Processing code to p5.js. I tried to write the code of p5.js, but it cannot be displayed anything on p5.js. The original file and my code are shown below.

This is my code:

```
function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
}
   var N = 100;
   var cx   = [0.000, 1.000, 0.500]; 
   var cy   = [0.000, 0.000, 0.866]; 
   var x = 0.0, y = 0.0; 
   
function draw(){
   for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
       nextPoint();
       drawPoint(); 
   } 
}
function drawPoint(){
  strokeWeight(1);
  var px = map(x,0,1.0,0,300);
  var py = map(y,0,1.0,0,300);
  point(px, py); 
}

function nextPoint() {
   let r = random(3);
    x = (x + cx[r]) / 2.0; 
    y = (y + cy[r]) / 2.0; 
}
```

This is source code:(form processing)

```
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
}
   int N = 100;
   float[] cx   = { 0.000, 1.000, 0.500 }; 
   float[] cy   = { 0.000, 0.000, 0.866 }; 
   float x = 0.0, y = 0.0; 
   
void draw(){
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
       nextPoint();
       drawPoint(); 
   } 
}
void drawPoint(){
  strokeWeight(1);
  float px = map(x,0,1.0,0,300);
  float py = map(y,0,1.0,0,300);
  point(px, py); 
}
void nextPoint() {
   int r = (int)random(3);
    x = (x + cx[r]) / 2.0; 
    y = (y + cy[r]) / 2.0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `floor()` when you define `r`. Although JavaScript doesn't have rigid data types for its variables like Java, it still doesn't know what you mean when you say something like `cx[1.348]`. When you use non-integer values for array access, you get `cx[1.348] = NaN`, and then when you try to draw a point at `NaN, NaN`, it doesn't do anything. So your code should say `let r = floor(random(3))` on line 23 (you might also consider setting the background color in `setup()`).